# MongoDB where combined value equals a given target value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Let's assume:

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc123", "price" : 2 },
   { "_id" : 2, "item" : "xyz123", "price" : 5 },
   { "_id" : 3, "item" : "ijk123", "price" : 12},
   { "_id" : 4, "item" : "fgh123", "price" : 14},
] )
```

A user has $17 dollars to spend, I need to return a combination of products for that budget. It should return:

```
   { "_id" : 2, "item" : "xyz123", "price" : 5 },
   { "_id" : 3, "item" : "ijk123", "price" : 12},
```

Is this possible? Currently, I'm pulling all the docs, then running a recursive function. But it uses a lot of memory.

Comment: should the price sum up to exactly $17 or can it be lower

Comment: It can be lower

Comment: you want only the one cost most or every combination. If it's the former one, then your example did it correct. If it's the later one, then your output should be all four documents since every document price is less than $17. And I think the best solution is only use `$lte:17` to find all documents which price is less than or equal to $17, then handle it in applicaition level.